# How is pixel data transferred from the GPU to the video memory?

Tags: opengl, video, graphics

I wrote a test animation program that has 500 translucent ellipses floating randomly. The main purpose of this is to test the performance of a software vector graphics library. I get around 170 FPS, which is good enough.

First I draw the whole frame in plain memory. Then I need a way to transfer this data to the video memory that the monitor accesses. It would be nice and simple to `memcpy` to the video memory directly, but no modern operating system will allow this. I can think of 2 options here.

The first one is to use the system blitting function, such as `BitBlt` in Windows or `XPutImage` in Unix systems.

The second is to copy the whole frame to the GPU as an OpenGL texture, and then draw the whole texture to the screen.

I tested both using the equivalent SDL wrappings. The performance in speed is nearly the same, as most of the time is spent on creating the frame to be drawn.

One noticeable difference is that going through the GPU produces a lot more smoother result. I see not 0 but less tearings. One possible reason I can think of is that maybe the moving of pixels from the GPU to the video memory is treated specially for maximum speed, differently from normal memory copying, so that the screen appears more 'instantly'.

So back to the title of this question, how is pixel data transferred from the GPU to the video memory? Is it just like a simple call to `memcpy` or are there some special treatings applied? If so, what are those?

Comment: *It would be nice and simple to memcpy to the video memory directly, but no modern operating system will allow this*, wrong. You can do that both with GDI and DirectX (I have not worked with OpenGL). When you create an `HBitmap` with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` or `LoadImage`, it resides in video memory. You just need a pointer to transfer the data. The same with the texture in DirectX

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε: Linux framebuffer device.

Comment: _"The second is to copy the whole frame to the GPU as an OpenGL texture, and then draw the whole texture to the screen."_ This kinda defeats the point of OpenGL, if you're rendering the scene yourself. Nevertheless, check out the [page on buffer object streaming](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) for efficient data uploading. `glBufferSubData` is enough like `memcpy`, and `glMapBuffer` lets you literally use `memcpy`.